# How to Delete or Refresh the content of DBMS_OUTPUT

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I have a PL/SQL script similar to this:

```
BEGIN  
    FOR r IN (
       SELECT DISTINCT id 
       FROM my_table
    ) 
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(r.id);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

After each execution of the script I have to manually refresh "DBMS Output" tab in Toad in order to see the results. Also, the results are being appended to what have been already output. I know that there aren't such procedures like dbms_output.clear(), dbms_output.remove() or dbms_output.delete() or dbms_output.refresh(), but it would be nice to have such.

**My questions are:**

- Is there a way to delete the content of DBMS_OUTPUT from within PL/SQL?
- Is there a way of automatic refreshing?

Comment: See this forum posts : [1](https://forums.toadworld.com/t/how-do-i-enable-dbms-output-by-default-i-e-have-it-always-on/41203/7),  [2](https://forums.toadworld.com/t/any-way-to-have-dbms-output-auto-clear-on-every-new-execution/29269/6)

Comment: @Eldar: The suggested question and solution didn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below,Also try wrapping it as a procedure and run in DB

```
BEGIN  
dbms_output.disable;
dbms_output.enable;
FOR r IN (SELECT DISTINCT id 
   FROM my_table  
LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(r.id);
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: It just enables/disables the output, but doesn't delete its content, nor refreshes it automatically. By the way, adding those 2 lines haven't changed the behavior and the resulted output of the script execution.

Comment: You get that output because the Oracle DBMS does not handle the results om dbms_output. Within Oracle dbms_output is just a buffer. The output is handled by the interfacing system; whether that be SQL Developer, SQL*Plus, or in your case Toad. Not clearing the display afterward and having to manually to clear the results is the way Toad handles it. It's been a few years since I've used Toad, so I'm not sure, but there may be a toad option to accomplish what  you want. But internally your dbms_output is gone.

Comment: Try wrapping it as a procedure

Comment: `dbms_output.disable` followed by `dbms_output.enable` does indeed clear the buffer, so the behaviour you are seeing is from Toad not PL/SQL. I don't have Toad and haven't used it in a while though, so I don't know what options are available.

Comment: For product questions you might have more luck on the [Toad World forums](https://forums.toadworld.com/c/toad-for-oracle/10).